# span element doesn't increase in width when using display: flex;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center a span-element in an container div. The span-element is preceeded by another div.

here is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <span id="b">B</span>
</div>

#container {
    display:flex;

    background-color:#0AA;
    text-align:center;
}

#a {
    width:70%;
    background-color:#AA0;
}
```

and on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pbek7av3/1/

I tried it with text-align:center and margin:auto, but sadly this doesn't work.

edit:
This would be another approach: http://jsfiddle.net/pbek7av3/2/
Is there something like width:auto; to let div b take the remaining space fo the parent container?

Comment: how you want to center, and what about the preceding div, what you want to do with that?

Comment: the preceeding div is fine, my goal is to center the span ("B") in the remaining space of the container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `display: flex;` for the parent, so `span` being an inline element, use `flex: 1;` which is nothing but grow for the flex item like

```
#b {
    flex: 1; /* Or flex-grow: 1; */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pbek7av3/5/) (Missed out the declaration in previous demo #3 so updated again)

Note that `flex` is not supported in older versions of IE as well as other popular browsers so if you are interested in the browser support than take a look at [CanIUse : Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for more details.

---

Test case **without** `flex: 1;` or `flex-grow: 1;`

[image: Without flex property]

With `flex: 1;` or `flex-grow: 1;`

[image: With flex property]

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there are only two element which is getting entire width i.e. one your div `width:70%`, then you can easily give the remaining `width:30%` to the `span` like this

```
#b {
    text-align:center;
    width:30%;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pbek7av3/4/)